# Custom SQL datediff function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

has anyone seen any custom code examples for determining a sensible difference between two dates. i.e similar to that on facebook.

- this was posted 2 seconds ago
- this was posted yesterday
- this was posted 4 hours ago.

Comment: It's probably something better done in your presentation layer (web app, desktop app, phone app, whatever).  You'd have date comparison code check to see if there are multiple days between the dates - if so, then it's dateDiff(...) days.  If not, then check for multiple hours.  If so, then it's hourDiff(...) hours.  If not, then check for multiple minutes...  And on through to seconds and perhaps if < 10 seconds, just say "a moment ago".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, in this scenario i think it would be too complex and to achieve nicely in SQL, added to the fact that clientside logic would be more efficient as i intended to use jQuery to update these values ala facecrack.

[Found this library which works perfectly for my purposes.](http://timeago.yarp.com/)

Answer (score 2):

While agreeing that this may be better done at the presentation layer, this could form the basis of a solution in SQL - if you need it on your SQL Server, you could of course also write a CLR function in the .Net language of your choice.

```
declare @d datetime = '2012-10-11 00:52'
select 
    case 
        when diff < 60 then convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(s, @d, getdate())) + ' seconds'
        when diff < 3600 then convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(MI, @d, getdate())) + ' minutes'
        when diff < 86400 then convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(hh, @d, getdate())) + ' hours'
        when diff < 604800 then convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(D, @d, getdate())) + ' days'
        when diff < 2419200 then convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(WEEK, @d, getdate())) + ' weeks'
        else convert(varchar(5), DATEDIFF(MONTH, @d, getdate())) + ' months'
    end
from
    (select DATEDIFF(s, @d, getdate()) as diff) v
```